# Flip flop hat, what did I do?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

I just got this flip flop hat. Whilst I find it extremly cool because it reminds me of the 5th doctor's hat, i'm confused to what I did to earn it.

[image: Flip flop]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789

Comment: ah, I was not aware of that thread, I usually only hang on this meta site

Comment: I got it immediately after receiving a silver badge, without upvoting things :/

Comment: I literally did nothing... I got a single upvote on a old thread of mine. I was just browsing between meta and overflow

Comment: Same here. I got one on ComputerScience, where I have not even any action in my all actions history.

Comment: I just got that hat, but is blue, coincided with an accepted and voted answer, besides the asker leave a comment in my answer, and I responded with another comment, I hope it will help you figure out, sorry for my English

Comment: You kept calm and hacked the world to get the hat

Comment: Ill take it @BhargavRao :-)

Comment: meta.SE is a terrible, terrible place. Stay here.

Comment: OK, but where does its name `"Flip Flop`" come from and how does it relate to the hat's award reason?

Comment: **What Spoilers You Insolent Fools!**

Comment: Did anyone receive 'both' the versions of this hat?

Comment: Maybe he used a flip-flop : )

Comment: What is the url that shows all our hats?

Comment: @user7 http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> It exists in two varieties, blue and white. You get this hat for [visiting a site and voting on December 21st](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127/238300).
>
>
>  The name is something to do with [the dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dress_(viral_phenomenon)) that was all over social media a while ago because some saw it in blue and black, while others saw it as white and gold.

Comment: Oh, and btw, it's actually Purple and Brown!

Comment: Whoever came up with this hat needs to be drug-tested ;).

Comment: @ChrisPratt Maybe (s)he was really testing drugs :)

Comment: Hmm... Following "the dress" link, I can see blue and black, but the Flip flop hat I got, it's white and gold ...?

Comment: @Teemu I think you get a "black and blue" or "white and gold" hat randomly, because the hats are not really an optical illusion

Comment: Wait, how did you hide that text?

Comment: But how'd you do it? Like, what did you put around the text? What symbol?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia you put >! At the start of each line

Comment: @RuchirBaronia You can just click the [edit] link to view the post's source code, after all.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - can I volunteer to be the control subject who's drugged but NOT tested..? :-)